# eclipse startup error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: startup, eclipse

I just installed the Eclipse IDE, but there seems to be an error when I execute Eclipse.exe.

Here's the log file:

```
!SESSION Wed Nov 28 18:42:12 IST 2018 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-11-28 18:42:12.757
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

what should I do?

Comment: I don't see an error. Why do you execute `Eclipse.exe` ? Are you using Windows? Start with `eclipse`

Comment: What version of Eclipse? What version of Java?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I downloaded eclipse using the "sudo apt-get eclipse" command. I think I used the wrong phrase when I wrote I "execute eclipse". I meant that I simply launched the eclipse application. But there does seem to be an error.